# Running python script on remote access device

Tags: python, remote-access

I have to run a python script on a device remotely to do some calculations. The code seems to run fine when I run it simply as  `python name.py`. However, when I run it as a submitted job using `qsub`, I get an error when it tries to generate the output and error files. After some playing around I found that problem we specifically just with generating the output and error files. Currently I am displaying my output using the `print()` command. My guess is that this does not work for the output of such jobs. But I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My PBS script is as follows:

```
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -q fourday
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=10
#PBS -l mem=20gb
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -N Quantum_Ising
#PBS -o Quantum_Ising.out
#PBS -e Quantum_Ising.err


cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR/
module load anaconda/py3.7
python Quantum_Ising.py
```